# Questions about Laravel API-Centric app

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am new to APIs. I want to make an API-centric Laravel web app and an Android app. They will use private API.

I am not sure how to make the user auth for the API. I have read many articles about JWT and many more about OAuth2 but I am still not sure which one to use and how to actually make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you read through this very digestable book - https://apisyouwonthate.com/.  It helps with the theory and the implementation of an API in Laravel.  Although the code is specifically for Laravel 4, virtually everything in the book is still helpful.

Starting in Laravel 5.2, the framework has been providing support for token authentication and web form authentication right out of the box. https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely read the book. I've already read about Laravel Passport but I can't understand how users register